# can't cast Array to - Multiple images with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

i am trying to use carrierwave to upload multiple images and when try to save i get this error

```
can't cast Array to
```

Telling me that the error is in the controller

```
if @property.save
```

I don´t know if its related but when i added this migration

```
rails g migration add_images_to_properties images:json
```

The schema presented this problem for the properties table

```
# Could not dump table "properties" because of following NoMethodError
```

## undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Everything else is in order ..

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploaders :images, ImageUploader
end

 def property_params
     params.require(:property).permit(:address, :price, :city, {images: []})
end


<div class="property-image">
    <h2>Cargar Imagenes</h2>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any clue??

Comment: Could you: 1. Add the exact code you are using?  This code is all over the place (e.g. is `def property_params` actually inside `class Property` or is it floating off somewhere else?). 2. Write exactly what you are doing to cause the error, and the full error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InIn your migration, you tried to create an "images" column with json as datatype.

As your schema.rb tels you, the database manager you are using failed to do so.

I assume you're using Sqlite3 as it is the default dbm on rails. 
Indeed, Sqlite can't handle json datatype

A good solution is to migrate your database from Sqlite to PostgreSql as it support json and as it is the default database manager on heroku.

If your on local machine, to migrate from Sqlite3 to PG :

1 - Install Postgresql on your local machine. Depending on your OS you can find what you need here : https://www.postgresql.org/download/

2- change your **gemfile** :

Remove :

```
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Add :

```
# Use postgres as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
```

3 - Run on your command line

```
$ bundle install
```

it will install the postgresql gem on your Rails application

4 - Update your **database.yml** file to make it works with your new DB

change your former file from

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

to this :

```
# 
#   gem install pg
#
#   Ensure the PostgreSql gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'pg'
#

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  password: the_password_you_set_when_installing_postgresql_on_your_machine
  username: postgres
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test
```

5 - Now you just have to make the migration from your command line:
First reset the db

```
$ rake db:setup
```

Then run the migrations

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

6 - Eventually restart your server

```
$ rails server
```